# Does ios app Metadata rejected means binary is good

Tags: ios, metadata, appstore-approval

I recently got a phone call from Apple saying they would reject our app since there's a problem with the metadata. I asked whether there's a problem with the app itself and she said she doesn't know because she's not part of the review team. She said it should be ok.

So I changed my metadata and resubmit the app, and the status now is in review. According to itunesconnect programmer guide, they will reuse the binary. Does that mean the binary is good? Is it possible that they will take a look at the app again and reject me for some reasons other than they specified in the resolution centre?

I know this is a question that probably only apple can answer, but this is our first app so i don't really know how it works. I asked apple but they didn't tell me anything.

Comment: Follow up: Our app has been approved last night and seems like they didn't do any other testing according to the system logs on the server. At least, not interacting with the server. So it could be just the metadata is wrong and they finished testing the binary before they called me. Anyway, thanks guys for your help and I wish this could help other people.

Comment: it's interesting to know that they actually make phone calls.

Comment: They called me the first time. They reject our app for the recent upgrade since they don't like the wordings we put for the app description. They didn't call this time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not need to upload new binary. They will review it again and approve it (or reject for other reason). It took only few hours in my case. But you can't be sure the binary has already been checked. Maybe they only did the metadata so far and will check the binary after your metadata correction. Anyway, no need to upload anything now.

Comment: "It took only few hours in my case." -- That's good to hear. Actually I was worrying about other things could get my app rejected since the related wordings are not clear in their review guidelines. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Did you have to submit the app for review again or you just replied in the resolution center?

Comment: After correcting the metadata, I resubmitted with the same binary.

Answer (score 13):

Usually reviewers stop their review process as soon as they find an issue. This means that the metadata rejection can be the first of a longer list (hopefully no!) or that they reviewed your whole app and found the only issue at metadata level only: in such case fixing your metadata should be enough.

Recently I saw one of my apps rejected due to a mistake in adding an In App Purchase (basically the app was referring to an IAP still not in iTunes). After fixing it (no binary change, just adding the "in app") they found an issue in the app this time and then the binary was submitted. It would have been quite easier for me to know of the two issues together and fix them once, instead the triple-trip delayed my final app submission by 10 extra days (consider 5 days between two consecutive reviews)

Comment: That's too bad. If they tell people at once with all the problems, it would save time for both sides. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 9):

From my experience, it doesn't always mean the **binary** is good. They may have very well reached the point of checking metadata and found an issue **without** testing the binary itself. Expect the Unexpected with Apple.

Comment: They definitely started testing before they call me as I have logs in my server side web service calls. Hopefully they are ok with my binary. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to metadata information, no need to upload  new binary. They will review it again and approve it (or reject for other reason). In my case, I was using location in background mode but in my Application description did not include the required "battery use" disclaimer,  I changed the meta data (Application description only) according to apple message. It took only few hours (hardly 4 hours) and application was live. I was socked :) because some people was saying, It will take upto 7 days(as apple normal process).

Following was reason for app reject in my case(Below was the mail, I received from Apple)

From Apple

* 2.16 - Multitasking Apps may only use background services for their
intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion,
local notifications, etc.

2.16 Details

Your app uses the Location Background mode but does not include the
required "battery use" disclaimer in your Application Description.

Next Steps

Please add the following disclaimer to your Application Description:

"Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically
decrease battery life."

Please see the app store screenshot for confirm.

[image]

Comment: Did you have to submit the app for review again or you just replied in the resolution center?

Comment: I submitted for review again and It took only few hours.

Comment: @genaks Please see the screenshot attached and time also.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, they reject the app as soon as they find a reason and they won't review it any further until next submission. So if the metadata is rejected it does not mean that they have approved the binary.

Comment: Are you sure this shouldn't be a comment? It doesn't provide any info that the other answers didn't already convey.