# Your app version has been metadata rejected. Please correct the issues and resubmit the new metadata

Tags: app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Your app version has been metadata rejected. Please correct the issues and resubmit the new metadata.

What causes this problem?

Comment: Go to the rejection centre and see why

Comment: @MCKapur its Resolution Center not Rejection Center :)

Comment: @anum90 I'd prefer Rejection Centre term here ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you got your app rejected, you can find out the reason by clicking on **View Details** button in app version you recently submitted. Then click **Resolution Center** button located on top-right corner. There you will find the issues posted by apple.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your metadata of your application on iTunes Connect if it's correct.

For more details, please take a look
[Does ios app Metadata rejected means binary is good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936300/does-ios-app-metadata-rejected-means-binary-is-good).

Answer (score 0):

friends 
not sure this will help 
but this is the link with better discription 
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/da/rejectionReasons?adamId=774935608